# how to make mavensmate sync a flow from salesforce platform to sublime

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I created a flow from the process builder , and I want to sync it locally.
When I looked at the project from mavensmate , I couldn't find the file which is named .flow

This is my first question in stackoverflow , I'm sorry about my poor english , hope you can understand what I described . who could give me some suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to update your local SF project metadata. For that, in SublimeText, go to MavensMate menu -> Project -> Edit Project. It should open the project metadata tab in your browser. Click the "Refresh" button and then choose the flow that you need in your project tree. Click "Update project". After that you should be able to find the flow in your project folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I still couldn't find the .flow file. Package.xml appeared <types><members>New_EMPL_Join_Chatter_Group_Auto</members>
        <name>Flow</name>
    </types>, this member is what I created, but there are still no folder named flows or something like that in project src. I'm confused about it. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hm, if you did project update and your package.xml contains the flow as a member, your project folder should contain folder "flows" and, possible, "flowDefinitions". Maybe your package.xml has very old version?

Comment: 34.0 is my package.xml version, I'm not sure if it's really very old.

Comment: That's really not pretty old version. Did you try to refresh whole project from SF sandbox? BTW, which version of MavensMate do you have? Possible flows are missed in mavensmate settings? I'm not sure, but maybe parameter "mm_apex_file_extensions", which contains project members extensions, affects it.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Mavensmate's settings.

Add ".flow" to the list of extensions under "SALESFORCE FILE EXTENSIONS (MM_APEX_FILE_EXTENSIONS)" if it isn't there already.

You might want to update "SALESFORCE API VERSION (MM_API_VERSION)" to the latest as well.

If your still having problems with that, you might want to check the Flow names including the version numbers.  In my case, Mavensmate shows Versions 1, 2, 3, and has no number after the current (active) version. The file on my hard drive is labelled as version 4, so the names don't match up.

To fix this, you'll want to deactivate the processes and update your project.

Comment: Thanks Dave,



I tried what you said and it worked well. I have another way to export metadata from Salesforce to local path.

Use [Foce.com CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/forcecli) to export data. for example: `force export Desktop/salesforceMetadata`